# Why do I have java.util.EmptyStackException when using HTMLUnit to render the page via Filter?

Tags: java, gwt, htmlunit

Ok, I have a Filter

```
public class CrawlServlet implements Filter{
   @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
      HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
      String requestQueryString = httpRequest.getQueryString();
      if ((requestQueryString != null) && (requestQueryString.contains("_escaped_fragment_"))) {
           String str="http://127.0.0.1:8888/Myproject.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#!article";
           // this url work fine, if i open it it will show article.
           final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
           HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(str);
           PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
           out.println(page.asXml());
      }

   }
}
```

Ok, now i ran my app in eclipse, & open the url  `http://127.0.0.1:8888/Myproject.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997?_escaped_fragment_=article`

Then I got this error in eclipse

```
    .GWTUpld .gwt-Button:HOVER,
.GWTUpld .DecoratedFileUpload .gwt-Button-over,
.GWTUpld .DecoratedFileUpload .gwt-Anchor-over,
.GWTUpld .DecoratedFileUpload .gwt-Label-over {
    color: #af6b29;
}
......
.GWTUpld input[type="file"] {
    cursor: pointer;
}


': null
java.util.EmptyStackException
    at java.util.Stack.peek(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Stack.pop(Unknown Source)
    at com.steadystate.css.parser.CSSOMParser$CSSOMHandler.endDocument(CSSOMParser.java:271)
    at com.steadystate.css.parser.AbstractSACParser.handleEndDocument(AbstractSACParser.java:456)
    at com.steadystate.css.parser.SACParserCSS3.styleSheet(SACParserCSS3.java:56)
    at com.steadystate.css.parser.AbstractSACParser.parseStyleSheet(AbstractSACParser.java:284)
    at com.steadystate.css.parser.SACParserCSS3.parseStyleSheet(SACParserCSS3.java:23)
    at com.steadystate.css.parser.CSSOMParser.parseStyleSheet(CSSOMParser.java:146)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleSheet.parseCSS(CSSStyleSheet.java:818)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleSheet.(CSSStyleSheet.java:179)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleSheet.loadStylesheet(CSSStyleSheet.java:321)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLLinkElement.getSheet(HTMLLinkElement.java:130)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.StyleSheetList.item(StyleSheetList.java:151)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Window.getComputedStyle(Window.java:1601)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Element.getCurrentStyle(Element.java:545)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomNode.isDisplayed(DomNode.java:712)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient$CurrentWindowTracker.webWindowContentChanged(WebClient.java:1671)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.fireWindowContentChanged(WebClient.java:742)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:440)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadDownloadedResponses(WebClient.java:2024)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:712)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.access$500(JavaScriptEngine.java:92)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:679)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:602)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:616)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:591)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:985)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptFunctionJob.runJavaScript(JavaScriptFunctionJob.java:53)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptExecutionJob.run(JavaScriptExecutionJob.java:102)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptJobManagerImpl.runSingleJob(JavaScriptJobManagerImpl.java:328)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.run(DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.java:162)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

May 16, 2014 1:36:41 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleSheet parseCSS
SEVERE: Error parsing CSS from '/**
* The file contains styles for GWT widgets in the standard theme.
 *
 * In order to maintain cross-browser compatibility, the following syntax is
 * used to create IE6 specific style rules:
 *    .gwt-Widget {
 *      property: rule applies to all browsers
 *      -property: rule applies only to IE6 (overrides previous rule)
 *    }
 *    * html .gwt-Widget {
 *      property: rule applies to all versions of IE
 *    }
 */
.......
': null
java.util.EmptyStackException
    at java.util.Stack.peek(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Stack.pop(Unknown Source)
    at com.steadystate.css.parser.CSSOMParser$CSSOMHandler.endDocument(CSSOMParser.java:271)
    at com.steadystate.css.parser.AbstractSACParser.handleEndDocument(AbstractSACParser.java:456)
    at com.steadystate.css.parser.SACParserCSS3.styleSheet(SACParserCSS3.java:56)
    at com.steadystate.css.parser.AbstractSACParser.parseStyleSheet(AbstractSACParser.java:284)
    at com.steadystate.css.parser.SACParserCSS3.parseStyleSheet(SACParserCSS3.java:23)
    at com.steadystate.css.parser.CSSOMParser.parseStyleSheet(CSSOMParser.java:146)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleSheet.parseCSS(CSSStyleSheet.java:818)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleSheet.(CSSStyleSheet.java:179)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleSheet.loadStylesheet(CSSStyleSheet.java:321)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLLinkElement.getSheet(HTMLLinkElement.java:130)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.StyleSheetList.item(StyleSheetList.java:151)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Window.getComputedStyle(Window.java:1601)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Element.getCurrentStyle(Element.java:545)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomNode.isDisplayed(DomNode.java:712)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient$CurrentWindowTracker.webWindowContentChanged(WebClient.java:1671)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.fireWindowContentChanged(WebClient.java:742)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:440)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadDownloadedResponses(WebClient.java:2024)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:712)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.access$500(JavaScriptEngine.java:92)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:679)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:602)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:616)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:591)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:985)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptFunctionJob.runJavaScript(JavaScriptFunctionJob.java:53)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptExecutionJob.run(JavaScriptExecutionJob.java:102)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptJobManagerImpl.runSingleJob(JavaScriptJobManagerImpl.java:328)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.run(DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.java:162)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Is this cos I have `/*** ***/` comment line in css & that is why the HtmlUnit could not parse?

Can you fix this issue?

Also, How can we make sure HTMLUnit will work OK in all kind of html code?

Note: I am using htmlunit-2.14

Extra info: this could be the code that cause the issue:

```
    May 16, 2014 1:36:41 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleSheet parseCSS
SEVERE: Error parsing CSS from '/**
 * The file contains styles for GWT widgets in the standard theme.
 *
 * In order to maintain cross-browser compatibility, the following syntax is
 * used to create IE6 specific style rules:
 *    .gwt-Widget {
 *      property: rule applies to all browsers
 *      -property: rule applies only to IE6 (overrides previous rule)
 *    }
 *    * html .gwt-Widget {
 *      property: rule applies to all versions of IE
 *    }
 */

body, table td, select {
  font-family: Arial Unicode MS, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
}
pre {
  font-family: "courier new", courier;
  font-size: small;
}
body {
  color: black;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #fff;
  direction: ltr;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing part of the error, specifically the beginning of the css in the first message - what else was there? Can you share the contents of your html page and any other css files that you have created? Also, where is there a `/*** ***/` - you haven't posted that source anywhere in your question.

Comment: If you think it might be the comment, what happens when you remove the comment?  Also, I've had a look on grepcode, and line 271 of CSSOMParser is a bit suspicious (two unguarded `pop()`s), so I'd be open to the possibility of a bug there.  You might have to be very defensive when writing your CSS and HTML files in this case. (Can't tell for sure without debugging)

Comment: @ Colin, i can not put more than 300000 into the question, but I did update my question, pls read the section "Extra info: this could be the code that cause the issue:"

Comment: @Paul, "defensive"?, you mean very conservative? no I just copy whatever solution on the internet as long as It work in eclipse. But i think HtmlUnit should be strong enough to handle all the complexity of css otherwise we never so sure if htmlunit works ok cos noone knows 100% how css behave

Comment: @Paul, i did remove the comment, but still get the same error

Comment: maybe this is the problem "!stack.empy() && stack.peek() .. stack.peek() is the one throwing this 
exception. May be that, when the current thread has checked !empty(), 
another thread has already consumed the data due to JVM memory model. May 
be we need to do in sych?? "http://htmlunit.10904.n7.nabble.com/htmlunit-Bugs-1728761-java-util-EmptyStackException-in-webclient-td4900.html